# git-svn undo a non-dcomitted merge

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn

On a `git-svn` checkout I accidentally merged a branch onto `trunk`:

```
git checkout -b my_branch
# make and commit changes
git checkout trunk
git svn rebase
git merge my_branch
# resolve conflicts
```

I did not `dcommit` yet but to me it looks like now I've lost the original `trunk` and have a shuffled commit history:

```
$ tig
2016-09-19 15:09 other-dev  o {trunk} remote changes
2016-09-19 15:01 me         o changes on my_branch
2016-09-19 14:55 other-dev  o remote changes
2016-09-19 14:33 me         o changes on my_branch
2016-09-19 13:58 me         o changes on my_branch
2016-09-19 13:44 other-dev  o remote changes
2016-09-19 11:48 me         o changes
2016-09-16 07:41 other-dev  o changes
```

I now think bad things will happen if I try to `dcommit` this state.

I'd like to 'undo' the whole merge, go back to `my_branch`, rebase `trunk` and re-do the merge.

The only idea I come up with is to checkout `remote/trunk`, delete `local/trunk` and re-branch `local/trunk` from `remote/trunk`.

Is there an easier way to 'undo' a merge in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why `tig` is not showing the merge actually. I tried to reproduce this and `tig` tries ordering the commits by date, even from different branches. But with the branch view it shows to me the branch like:

```
2016-09-20 13:31 me M─┐ [master] Merge branch 'foo'
2016-09-20 13:31 me o │ f
2016-09-20 13:30 me │ o [foo] e
2016-09-20 13:29 me o │ d
2016-09-20 13:28 me o │ c
2016-09-20 13:27 me │ o b
2016-09-20 13:17 me I─┘ a
```

and if I switch off branch view with 'G'

```
2016-09-20 13:31 me [master] Merge branch 'foo'
2016-09-20 13:31 me f
2016-09-20 13:30 me [foo] e
2016-09-20 13:29 me d
2016-09-20 13:28 me c
2016-09-20 13:27 me b
2016-09-20 13:17 me a
```

similar to yours, except that there are no `o` commit markers and the merge commit is shown.

---

Besides that, just look at the reflog of `master` with `git reflog master` to find the SHA of the master commit before your merge and then simply reset master to that commit with `git reset --hard <good commit-ish>` while having `master` checked out, or `git branch -f master <good commit-ish>` if you are not on master and don't want to check it out right now.

Comment: I did it quite similar now but made a mistake in the first place which led to missing merge info in the log (I don't want to talk about it). The approach you provided works so I will mark it as answer!